# How to install maps2winbugs for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation

I have got a maps2winbugs.dll file, but what should I do to install it into QGIS, sorry for the first time using this software, doesn't have any experients in C or R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Copy your dll into the QGIS Lisboa plugins folder:
[image: Copy the dll into QGIS Lisboa plugins folder]

2) Restart QGIS Lisboa and go to Plugins/Manage Plugins menu to open the QGIS Plugin Manager:
[image]

3) Check the maps2WinBUGS plugin, press OK and voilà:
[image]

Comment: Any reason there is a DLL and not just done in python